# Attempting to insert new row into database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ok, so I've been trying to do this for days, and I've been reading all sorts of tutorials, but I seem to be missing something, because I still can't get it. I'm working on learning about web forms and inserting the form input into the respective database. I'm able to take the info from the form and echo it on the result page, so I know that all works. but I can't seem to get the form input to go into my database. I know the connection works, so there must be something wrong with my syntax.

**PHP**

```
//DB Configs
    $username = null;
    $password = null;

    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Testing3", $username, $password);
        //Set the PDO error mode to exception (what does this mean?)
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //Prepare SQL and bind parameters
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `NFK_SPECIES` (`Name`)
            VALUES (:name)");

        //Insert a Row
        $species = $_POST['Species'];
        $sql->execute(array(':name'=>$species));

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * from `NFK_Species` ORDER BY `Id` DESC');
    //Query
    /*
    $input = $db->query("INSERT INTO `NFK_Species` (`Id`, `Name`) VALUES (Null, `$species`)");

    $result = $db->query('SELECT * from `NFK_Species` ORDER BY `Id` DESC');*/

    //Kill Connection
    $db = Null;
}
```

**HTML/PHP (web page)**

```
<h1>Inserting a New Species into Database:</h1>
    <h3>Results</h3>
    <?php
    if ($sql->execute()){
        echo "Data input was successful";
        while ($rows = $result->fetch()){
            echo $rows['Name']; echo ", ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Data input failed."; echo mysql_error();

    }
    ?>
```

This is only my current attempt at doing this. I prefer the attempt I had before, with the `bindParam` and simple `execute()`, so if I could get that to work instead, I'd appreciate it. The following example also has the `Id` column for this table. This is an auto-increment column, which I read doesn't need to be included, so I excluded it from my recent attempt. Is that correct?

**Past PHP**

```
//Prepare SQL and bind parameters
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `NFK_SPECIES` (`Id`, `Name`)
            VALUES (Null, :name)");
        $sql->bindParam(':name', $species);

        //Insert a Row
        $species = $_POST['Species'];
        $sql->execute();
```

I've been reading a bunch of tutorials (or trying to), including attempting to decipher the php.net tutorials, but they all seem to be written for people who already have a good handle on this and experience with what's going on, and I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: show us the form then. Plus `mysql_error()` if that is part of your working code, it doesn't belong with PDO. You're also using this `$species = $_POST['Species'];` **after** you're binding.

Comment: Remove the `if ($sql->execute()){}` from the fetch loop, because _already_ executed the statement.   Because it is wrapped in a `try/catch`, you can proceed directly into the fetch loop.

Comment: In the 'Past PHP' block you have the bind line before you set the species variable. That is neither here nor there at the mement because the first example looks good. What results are you getting--what sql error is being thrown

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` because I would expect an exception to be thrown on that second execution with no bound parameter.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - This code is actually killing my page, nothing shows up, when I know something should. Where do I put the error_reporting in my code? I'd love to know why it isn't working.

Comment: @ShirleyDodson Place the error reporting lines at the very top. Always do so when developing and testing code - or enable those two settings in your php.ini if you have access to do so.  If it's killing your page, there is a fatal error somewhere we've not yet spotted

Comment: Incidentally, the setAttribute() to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION you had a question on in the code configures PDO to throw an exception on any error. Its default behavior is to error silently, wherein you need to check the return values of all its methods (like `if (!$stmt = $pdo->prepare()...)` The exception method is considerably easier to debug.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - I found the bug. If you look at my 1st sample code, there is a stupid little "}" hanging out at the bottom that serves no purpose.  I got rid of that, and then the ERRMODE told my I couldn't log in to my database. Which if you look at my $usename and $password, they have (somehow) been stupidly set to NULL. HOW DOES THAT HAPPEN?! In any case, the code works now and I have successfully entered my row. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. I assumed the `}` was just a copy/paste leftover from a larger code block, and that the user/pass nulls were just there to redact your real info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I was able to figure out my problem, and then successfully insert a row using my code.

**Debugging:**

So the code posted above was breaking my code, meaning my page wouldn't load. I figured that meant that there was a syntax error somewhere, but I couldn't find it, and no one else had located it yet. Also, that meant that my `Error Alerts` weren't working to let me know what the problem was. If you look at my original PHP sample, you'll see down at the very bottom there is a single `"}"` just hanging out and serving no purpose, but more importantly, it's breaking the code (stupid, hyper-sensitive php code). So I got rid of that, and then my Error messages started working. It said I couldn't connect to my database. So I look over my database login syntax, which looked fine, and then you'll notice in my 1st php sample that somehow I'd managed to set my `$username` and `$password` to `NULL`. Clearly that isn't correct. So I fixed that, and next time I refreshed my page, I'd successfully entered a row in my database! (yay)

**Note:**

In my original php sample, I'd included the `Id` Column, which is auto-incremented, for the row insertion, with a value of `NULL`. This worked, and it inserted the row. Then I experimented with leaving it out altogether, and it still worked. So the updated working code below doesn't include the Species Id.

**Working code:**

```
<body>
    <h1>Inserting a New Species into Database:</h1>
    <h3>Results</h3>

    <?php

        //DB Configs
        $username = root;
        $password = root;

        try {
            //Connect to Database
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Testing3", $username, $password);
            //Enable PDO Error Alerts
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //Prepare SQL statement and bind parameters
            $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `NFK_SPECIES` (`Name`) VALUES (:name)");
            $sql->bindParam(':name', $species);

            //Insert a Row
            $species = $_POST['Species'];
            $sql->execute();

            // Echo Successful attempt
            echo "<p class='works'><b>" . $species . "</b> successfully added to database.</p></br></br>";

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        // Gather updated table data
        $result = $db->query('SELECT * from `NFK_Species` ORDER BY `Id` DESC');

        //Kill Connection
        $db = Null;

    while ($rows=$result->fetch()){
        echo $rows['Id']; echo " - ";  echo $rows['Name']; echo "</br>";
    }
    ?>

<body>
```